# PDF Preview in library

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a library full of pdf's. Is it possible to show a preview of this documents in the library view?
The preview is necessary because there are 5 user which work in the library and add the metadata. Everybody has a different department and should only work on their department documents. The documents are scanned documents which are sended via e-mail into the library. Therefore there is no possibility to differentiate the documents. Each new filename starts with the scan date + scan time.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to SharePoint 2013, it has this preview feature. There are also third party SharePoint add-ons for 2010 that can do the same thing, but they would need to be purchased and installed as well.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. SharePoint 2013 isn't yet an option :o(
So i have to take a look around for some third party solutions